# Why Universal Reference concept not working for map insert in case of function pointers

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, forwarding-reference

Can someone explain why below piece of code is not working if I don't use explicitly std::pair with map insert :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
typedef std::shared_ptr<int>(*CreatorFunction)();
std::shared_ptr<int> test()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
    return p;
}
int main()
{
  std::map<int, CreatorFunction> tmap; 
  tmap.insert(1,test); //this doesn't work
  tmap.insert(std::pair<int,CreatorFunction>(1,test)); //this works
 return 0;
}
```

My understanding is in c++14 we don't need to use std::pair as insert function definition is changed to accept universal reference as indicated below :

```
template <class P> pair<iterator,bool> insert (P&& val);
```

Comment: That overload takes one argument. You're passing two. It can't possibly be selected.

Comment: @Matt, Sorry my bad. Is there any way to delete this question

Comment: If you insist on it, there should be a "delete" link under the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any overload in `std::map::insert` that takes two arguments you should use `std::make_pair`. See the snippet below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

#include <functional> // for std::function.

// typedef std::shared_ptr<int>(*CreatorFunction)();
typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<int>()> CreatorFunction; // The c++ way.

// Take a look at this function. std::shared_ptr<int> will automatically destroy the int* and might result in undefined.
std::shared_ptr<int> test()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    std::map<int, CreatorFunction> tmap; 
    tmap.insert(std::make_pair(1,test)); // edited this line
    tmap.insert(std::pair<int,CreatorFunction>(1,test)); // this works
    return 0;
}
```